# How to clone heroku repository files

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I am trying to clone an old repository on heroku using :

```
heroku git:clone -a myAppName
cd myAppName
```

After that i found that the repository is empty.

How I can obtain the old code files using git instructions ? .

My config file :

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "heroku"]
    url = https://git.heroku.com/myAppName.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
[atomGithub]
    historySha = 7f8cf23d3570179d6f8dc02a552003b8634c1ca8
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://git.heroku.com/myAppName.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "main"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/main
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Is the code also on GitHub or similar? In general, you should clone from GitHub or GitLab or Bitbucket or wherever your code lives. [Heroku should _not_ be used as your main repository](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app): "A Heroku app’s Git repository is intended for deployment purposes only. Cloning from this repository is not officially supported as a feature and should be attempted only as a last resort. **Do not** use this repository as your app’s canonical “origin” repository. Instead, use your own Git server or a version control service such as GitHub."

Comment: If this is your only copy, are you _entirely sure_ the repository contains your code? Did you `git push` to it before? If you deployed via GitHub or Docker, Heroku's repository won't contain your code.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this is my only copy, I lost my own github old one. when I cloned from heroku I am not able to see the source code, is there anyway to obtain it from heroku?

Comment: Again, did you deploy via `git push`, GitHub, or Docker? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, but after heroku git:clone -a myappname, I have a warning : You appear to have cloned an empty repository, although the site is working.

Comment: I have asked how you deployed this app twice. "Yes" does not answer the question. There are options: via `git push`, via GitHub integration, via Docker, and possibly others (e.g. one-click buttons, via the platform API...). _Which one did you use?_

Comment: i don not remember either git push or via GitHub integration.

Comment: Well if it was via GitHub integration you won't be able to get your code back via `git clone`. The empty result makes sense. I suggest you check your app's configuration to see if it's linked to a GitHub repository. And I suggest you try to recover your GitHub account, since it sounds like the code might still live there.

Comment: it is linked via heroku cli, not github, I think the only solution is to recover the repository on github. can I ask heroku team to provide me with original source code ?